# Load local dataset into Python 3.4 Pandas statsmodel for Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I'm trying to implement Time series forecasting in Python using Pandas n statsmodels. I want to read a local excel file data and then decompose it into Trends & Seasonal components but I'm unable to get any relevant links which shows how to load data from local drive.

I tried using the following code:

```
    excel = pandas.ExcelFile( 'PET_PRI_SPT_S1_D.xls' )
    df = excel.parse( excel.sheet_names[1] )
    dta = sm.datasets.co2.load_pandas().data
    dta.co2.interpolate(inplace=True)
    res = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(dta.co2)
    resplot = res.plot()
    res.resid
```

But its if I try printing **dta** variable, it shows some other data and not **PET_PRI_SPT_S1_D.xls**. Even resplot=res.plot() doesn't seem to work and no plot shows up.

Can you please guide me on how to load data from local drive into pandas dataframe.

*Edit 1:*

I get following when I tried **df.info()**. Here df is object of my excel file.

***DatetimeIndex: 7509 entries, 1986-01-24 00:00:00 to 2015-06-08 00:00:00 Data columns (total 2 columns): WTI 7408 non-null object Brent 7115 non-null object dtypes: object(2) memory usage: 117.3+ KB***

When I try **dta.info()** where dta is object of sm.datasets.co2 type, I get following.

***DatetimeIndex: 2284 entries, 1958-03-29 00:00:00 to 2001-12-29 00:00:00 Freq: W-SAT Data columns (total 1 columns): co2 2284 non-null float64 dtypes: float64(1) memory usage: 35.7 KB***

Comment: `dta` is the CO2 data, not your Excel file, which is `df`. Have you pasted the wrong code into your question?

Comment: I tried running the code again with some changes.
I tried 
_dta = df.load_pandas().data_
 and I get following error:
**AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'load_pandas'**

When I try _res = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df)_ , I get following error:
**TypeError: Cannot interpolate with all NaNs.***

Comment: It sounds as if your Excel file is not reading correctly. You'll need to tune the loading of the file to ensure you've got all the data read in. I imagine `df.info()` will show no non-null values.

Comment: I tried adding my results as comment but the length exceeded its limit hence posted is as another comment. Thanks. Kindly look into it.

Comment: You should better edit the question, not post it in a comment or add an answer

Comment: Hi, help would be appreciated. Thanks. :)